# oracle query to split data into per-date rows

Tags: oracle

I need to create a report which splits the values from table A into a row-by-date format.
So for example If I create a sub-set of dates for the past week and sales in the past week,
I need to output the 'REPORT OUTPUT' format. Just struggling to think of a way to 'loop' through the dates in date_range and say find sales in sales_in_range and do a count, then output the results.

```
WITH
    date_range (date_val)
    as
    (select sysdate-7 + level 
     from dual 
     connect by level <= ( sysdate - (sysdate-7))
    ),

    sales_in_range (itemcode,sale_date,value)
    as
    (select itemcode,sale_date,value 
     from sale_table 
     where sale_date between (sysdate-7) and (sysdate)
    );

-- REPORT OUTPUT SQL

;
```

Sub queries provide the below information.

Date Range:

```
select * from date_range
date_val
12-NOV-21
13-NOV-21
14-NOV-21
15-NOV-21
16-NOV-21
17-NOV-21
18-NOV-21
```

Sales in date range:

```
select * from sales_in_range;
itemcode    sale_date   value
00001       12-NOV-21   0
00002       13-NOV-21   0
00003       15-NOV-21   0
00004       15-NOV-21   0
00005       16-NOV-21   0
00006       16-NOV-21   0
00007       16-NOV-21   0
00008       18-NOV-21   0
00009       18-NOV-21   0
00010       18-NOV-21   0
```

REPORT OUTPUT:

```
sale_date   sale_count
12-NOV-21   1
13-NOV-21   1
14-NOV-21   0
15-NOV-21   2
16-NOV-21   3
17-NOV-21   0
18-NOV-21   3
```

Thanks in advance

K

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure what the purpose of the query you've written so far is supposed to be, but any reason you can't just simply use the [`GROUP BY` clause with the `COUNT()` aggregate function](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/group_by.php) on your `sale_table` like so?

```
SELECT sale_date, COUNT(*) AS sale_count
FROM sale_table
GROUP BY sale_date
ORDER BY sale_date
```

If you need to filter on just a certain date range, then you can add a `WHERE` clause also (assuming `sale_date` is of a date-based data type):

```
SELECT sale_date, COUNT(*) AS sale_count
FROM sale_table
WHERE sale_date >= TO_DATE('SomeStartDate', 'SomeDateFormat')
    AND sale_date < TO_DATE('SomeEndDate', 'SomeDateFormat')
GROUP BY sale_date
ORDER BY sale_date
```